# Group SQL rows with same value and add group headings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this but everything I find seems far too over complicated... starting to think I cant find it because it's so simple!

Anyway, I've got a database of food menu items, all of which are categorised as Starter, Main, Dessert, etc.

I can output all items sorted by category (Starters first, then the mains, then desserts) but I want to add a header to the top of each group so they look more like this...

STARTERS

- Soup
- Pate
- Another Starter...

MAINS

- Steak
- Fish & Chips
- Other Tasty Stuff

DESSERTS

- You get the idea...

Up to now I've got a table containing the food items joined to a table with the a course_id and the following SQL produces an ordered list but without the headings

```
$sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM food_items 

        INNER JOIN course_id
            ON food_items.course = course_id.course

        ORDER BY course_id
        ";
```

Then I've got the PHP...

```
$result = $con->query($sql);        
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
echo '<p class="menuItem">' . $row["item"] . ' - £' . $row["price"] . '</p>';
};
```

I've read about ROLLUP, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, etc but I can seem to figure out the best way without over complicating things...

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated

Cheers in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your current PHP code as is, with a slight modification. You will want to add a variable that tracks the current `category`, and write out a new one when it changes:

```
$result = $con->query($sql);        
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
    $curCategory = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if($curCategory != $row["category"])
        {
            $curCategory = $row["category"];
            echo '<p class="menuCategory"><strong>' . $curCategory . '</strong></p>';
        }
        echo '<p class="menuItem">' . $row["item"] . ' - £' . $row["price"] . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Of course, you will want to ensure your resultset from your query is sorted accordingly.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much! Knew it wouldn't be too complicated but as you can probably tell, I'm a bit of a PHP / SQL novice!
Thanks again, much appreciated